# Convert all % with decimal in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, character, percentage

I have a large data frame where the percentages are written as 10% and not .1. Not all columns are percentage, but quite a few are.

Is there an elegant way to convert all % into decimals? I'm especially concerned where percentages might be greater than 100% and that the rule can be applied to the entire tibble instead of me having to figure out which columns to target.

Example if not clear...
this:

```
tibble(cola = c("hello", "good bye", "hi there"), colb = c("10%", "20%", "100%"), colc = c(53, 67, 89),cold = c("10%", "200%", "50%") )
```

to this:

```
tibble(cola = c("hello", "good bye", "hi there"), colb = c(.10, .20, 1.0), colc = c(53, 67, 89),cold = c(.10, 2.0, .5) )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write an auxiliary function and `mutate_if` based on its value.

```
is.percentage <- function(x) any(grepl("%$", x))

df1 %>%
  mutate_if(is.percentage, ~as.numeric(sub("%", "", .))/100)
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  cola      colb  colc  cold
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 hello      0.1    53   0.1
#2 good bye   0.2    67   2  
#3 hi there   1      89   0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `across/mutate` where we select columns that have `character` class and (`&&`) `any` value having the `%`, `mutate` `across` those columns, extract the numeric part with `parse_number` and divide by 100

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(where(~ is.character(.) &&
         any(str_detect(., "%"))), ~ readr::parse_number(.)/100))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  cola      colb  colc  cold
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 hello      0.1    53   0.1
#2 good bye   0.2    67   2  
#3 hi there   1      89   0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Using baseR, we can get the column names where all entries end with "%", substitute the "%" at the end of the string by "" and divide by 100.

```
idx <- rapply(dat, f = function(x) all(endsWith(x, "%")), classes = "character")
dat[names(idx)[idx]] <- lapply(dat[names(idx)[idx]], function(x) {
  as.integer(sub("%$", "", x)) / 100L
  })
```

Result

```
dat
#      cola colb colc cold
#1    hello  0.1   53  0.1
#2 good bye  0.2   67  2.0
#3 hi there  1.0   89  0.5
```

**data**

```
dat <-
  data.frame(
    cola = c("hello", "good bye", "hi there"),
    colb = c("10%", "20%", "100%"),
    colc = c(53, 67, 89),
    cold = c("10%", "200%", "50%")
  )
```